# Solving $\vec y'=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1\\ \end{pmatrix}\vec y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve $\vec y'=\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & -1 \\
        0 & 1\\
        \end{pmatrix}\vec y$.

The characteristic polynomial is $(r-1)^2$, so the only eingenvalue is $1$.

I found only one eigenvector - $\begin{pmatrix}
        c_1 \\
        0\\
        \end{pmatrix}$.

(I know it doesn't have to be written with $c_1$, but it's to emphazise what happens next)

Trying to find the next vector in the method of Jordan, I got:

$\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & -1 \\
        0 & 0\\
        \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
        a \\
        b\\
        \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
        c_1 \\
        0\\
        \end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
        a \\
        b\\
        \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
        c_2 \\
        -c_1\\
        \end{pmatrix}$

So the solution is...?

$\vec y(x)= c_1 \begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        0\\
        \end{pmatrix}e^x+c_1\begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        0\\
        \end{pmatrix}xe^x+c_1\begin{pmatrix}
        0 \\
        -1\\
        \end{pmatrix}e^x+c_2\begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        0\\
        \end{pmatrix}e^x$

The fact that the two vectors are dependent really confuses me.

P.s- I know how to solve this by calculating $exp(Ax)$, but I am asked to do it this way here.